# How can I forward touch event to view under it

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, swift

I have a custom view that covers all the screen. This custom view has a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. I want this view to swallow all touch events EXCEPT for a specific region on screen.

I tried using `ShouldReceiveTouch` but it doesn't work

```
UserInteractionEnabled = true;
var gesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer(OnTouch);
gesture.ShouldReceiveTouch += (recognizer, touch) => 
{
    var point = recognizer.LocationInView(null);
    var res = ... // my condition to see if has or not to receive touch;
    return res;
};
AddGestureRecognizer(gesture);
```

How can I swallow all touch events except those on a specific area where I have a button that needs to be clicked? **My problem is that I don't know how to forward the event**. I know how to detect if the point of the touch matches with the area I want to forward touch event.

Solution can be on any language available for iOS development, my code is on C# since I'm using Xamarin but that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override this method of UIView:

```
open func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
```

check if point is in specific area. Return `true` if it is, and and `false` if is not.

You can find more details here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest